# display different image size in opencart php

Tags: php, opencart

I have following image names in my opencart directory `/image/cache/data`

```
1. 15-40x40.jpg
2. 15-62x62.jpg
3. 15-100x100.jpg
4. 15-160x160.jpg
5. 15-200x200.jpg
6. 15-455x475.jpg
7. 15-800x800.jpg
```

if i use echo `$thumb` it is showing the image `15-800x800.jpg` but how can i call the image `15-100x100.jpg`

Can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '800x800', '100x100' values shows the dimension of images. Opencart uses resized versions of original images in its webpages. You can change the image dimensions in opencart admin: `System > Settings > Store [Edit] >  Image` tab. The option that you're searching for may be `Product Image Thumb Size:` in `Image` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Images (thumbnails) are often created by code similar to this on:

```
$this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
```

(this is for the category image on category page). Here the *width* and *height* sizes are comming from DB, table `setting`, or in other words You can set them in You admonistration - `System -> Setting` - edit store, tab *Image*.

But if You need to do this in certain modules differently and do not want to create a new setting for this (since You know You won't change this in near future or not so often), You can simply call Your thumb as this:

```
$this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], 100, 100);
```

Change that `$this->data['thumb']` and `$category_info['image']` parts in Your controller to meet Your needs...